# Is there any difference between org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 & com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64?

Tags: java, base64

May be it is not a programming question, but i want to clarify

Is there any difference between `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` & `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64`?

Some of my J2EE application classes are using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and some are using `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64`.

I want to change to `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` as it is stable.

Already my app is running fine,but after the change will it continue to run fine i.e.,
will the encoding done by `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64` method be able to decode through `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` method?

I just want to clarify before i make a change to my production code.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always avoid using classes from com.sun.* packages directly. These are internal classes used to implement the JVM. They can be changed without notice on every update, thus breaking your code.

Base64 is standardized by the IETF, so both implementations should produce the same output. [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)

Comment: I think the apache one conforms to RFC 2045, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: RFC2045 describes the MIME format, not the Base64 encoding. As written above the currently valid document about Base64 is RFC4648.